# Is there an HTML5 way to conditionally exclude script tags on headless browsers?

Tags: html, prerender, google-chrome-headless

We use a prerender-type software that renders our single page app for crawlers and we'd like to exclude all third-party `script` tags where we pay by the impression. Loading them dynamically in JS with `writeln` or by creating a dom element means waiting until the JS is parsed to import what are very important libraries (like Optimizely -- we want to load it as early as possible to avoid dom flashes).

Is there something similar to `<!-- if[IE] -->` contitional comments that we can use to exclude blocks from headless browsers?

Answer (score 0):

First off, make sure those script tags you'll be blocking aren't modifying the page. You don't want to serve a different page to the crawlers than you are serving to your users since that can be seen as cloaking.

If you are using Headless Chrome directly with something like chrome-remote-interface, you can use `setBlockedURLs` found here:
https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/third_party/WebKit/Source/core/inspector/browser_protocol.json

If you are hosting your own Prerender server, check out the plugin for blocking certain URLs: https://github.com/prerender/prerender/blob/chrome/lib/plugins/blockResources.js

If you are using our hosted Prerender service, send us an email and we can help block those for you with our hosted service.

Comment: Interesting. We've been using rendertron but we may switch back to prerender. In regard to cloaking -- we just don't want to load all of our tracking pixels and AB testing software (which we pay for by impression) on our bot pages. Since we're recaching pages after any content change (ie new comments, new votes, etc) those numbers can add up.

Comment: Yep! When using Prerender, you can change the blocked Resources pretty easily.